# How to prove that finite co-finite algebras are not $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty infinite set and let $\alpha=\{E \subseteq X:E\ \text{is finite or X\E is finite}\}$ be an algebra of subsets of $X$ on $X$. Prove that it is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

I cannot prove that if $ \{E_j\}_{j=1}^\infty $ are subsets of $ X $ then $ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{i} $ belongs to $ X$ as well.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: You're missing at least one part of the hypothesis, that X is not merely non empty, but infinite.

Comment: I proved that it is closed under compliment operation. I edited and wrote what i cannot how above.

Comment: For the definition of $\alpha$, should it be "$E$ or $X\setminus E$ is finite"?

Comment: @Frank yes, I edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following two cases:

1. If $X$ is countably infinite, then we can enumerate the elements in $X$, say
   $$X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,\}$$
   Then simply define $E_n=\{x_{2n}\}$, clearly each $E_n$ is a member of $\alpha$, but neither $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ nor $X\setminus\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)$ is finite. Hence $\alpha$ is not closed under taking countable union.
2. If $X$ is uncountable, simply take $(E_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to be a family of pairwise disjoint singleton sets, then the same argument in the first case also works.

Comment: Great. I have just started Measure Theory and it is still difficult for me make this kind of arguments. Thanks was awesome!

Comment: @G.T. No problem!